# Json not displying FAQ list properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I just found out I cannot use "Newsletter style" for my FAQ lists in a modern site. If I use that the entire site will switch between classic and modern style. So I am trying some list formatting with JSON.

The problem is that the answer column is not displaying properly. The thing is that this field could contain pictures and tables, etc so I just want the JSON to take the contents and display all of it, and skip displaying div information.

How can I adjust the display of the answer so it just displays the contents?

[image]

```
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-row-card"
    },

    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "left"
        },

        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-title"
            },

            "txtContent": "[$Title]"
          },

          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-listPadding"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Answer]"
          }
        ] 
      } 
    ]  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text** is currently **not supported** in SharePoint online JSON formatting.

> The following column types are **not** supported currently:
>
> - Managed Metadata
> - Filename (in Document Libraries)
> - Retention Label
> - Sealed columns
> - **Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text**

**Microsoft official reference**: [SharePoint Online JSON formatting - Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

Comment: Oh, no! Lists are perfect for FAQs, but maybe I have to convert all my list items to pages then...

Comment: Yes. If you have fixed number of questions then you can create pages for each question and then link the pages with list item. So whenever you will click on json formatted question it will redirect you to particular question page.

Comment: I tried and It does not seem to work with 'plain' rich text either (even though it is not listed in the 'not supported list').